# Navigation Search (e.g. by filename) - Omit Unversioned files

Tags: intellij-idea, version-control, intellij-14

Is it possible to modify the standard IntelliJ searches (Navigate => [File|Symbol|Class]) so that they omit unversioned files?

One case where this would be beneficial:
I'm working on a project with bower and it becomes a pain trying to quickly navigate to bower.json (searching by name) of one of my modules when all the "bower.json"s of unversioned dependencies (and dependencies of dependencies) I have downloaded fill up the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no such option as of IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.

Comment: I'm thinking that is the case for out of the box functionality. Is there possibly a plug-in for this? I've looked around without any luck.

Comment: The plugin API does not allow plugins to filter items from the Goto Class/File/Symbol lists.

Comment: Alright, Thanks! Accepting this answer until that changes (or someone can prove otherwise).